# AngularJS convert modal to plain html site

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal-dialog

Hi I have a following code. It is opening **modal** with **example-site.html** inside.

```
              onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
                    $uibModal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'example-site.html',
                        controller: 'ExampleController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm',
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        size: 'md'
                    }).result.then(function () {
                        $state.go('example-site', {reload: false});
                    }, function () {
                        $state.go('^');
                    });
                }]
```

I would like to convert this modal to plain html that contain example-site.html. Any ideas?